# NXLOG how to merge multilines regex

Tags: regex, multiline, nxlog

I have a log like this:

```
14:40:33.476 [WebContainer : 149] sometihng sometihng 
14:40:33.476 [WebContainer : 149] sometihng sometihng 
14:40:33.476 [WebContainer : 149] sometihng sometihng 
14:40:33.476 [WebContainer : 245] csometihng sometihng 
14:40:33.476 [WebContainer : 245] sometihng sometihng 
14:40:33.476 [WebContainer : 245] sometihng sometihng
```

I use nxlog to send this to kafka, what I want is to merge all lines with "WebContainer : 149" into one, and next line when this changes and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex to capture all the lines with a certain value:

```
/(.*\[WebContainer : (\d+)\]\s*(.*))+\s+.*\[WebContainer : \2\]\s(.*)+\s+.*\[WebContainer : \2\]\s(.*)+/g
```

The regex matches any number of any char up to '`[WebContainer :` ', then matches any number and a right Square bracket before matcing White Spaces.

Then it starts all over Again (a new line), only here it uses capturing Group 2 to specify the number. This is repeated on the third line.

**Then replace the matches with :**

```
$1$3$4
```

Now you will get one line per number, combining the `'sometihng`' from each line.

Comment: This works for this particular case, but what if we don't know how many lines will the webcontainer: 123 will have (but a finite number). And forget about this something:)

Comment: You can't add an unknown number of lines. Then it becomes multiple matches and can't be replaced with back references.

Comment: If you want to add one line, you can add '\s+.*\[WebContainer : \2\]\s(.*)+' to the regex and '$5' to the replacement.